# Bootstrap Element 100% Width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, width

I want to create alternating 100% colored blocks. An "ideal" situation is illustrated as an attachment, as well as the current situation.

Desired setup:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/aiEMJ.jpg]

Currently:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/3Sl27.jpg]

My first idea was to create an div class, give it a background color, and give it 100% width.

```
.block {
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
}
```

However, you can see that this obviously doesn't work. It's confined to a container area. I tried to close the container and that didn't work either.

Comment: Could you include the code you are working with? Without that, all I can say is you'd have to make sure the containing tags for the div do not have width set other than 100%

Comment: Hey Michael, thanks for the response. Here's the section of the code I'm working with:

`<div class="container">  
    
    <div class="row">  
     <div class="span12"><img src="img/logo.png" width="960px"></center></div>  
    
    <div class="block">content</div>`

Comment: Recent versions of bootstrap have aspect ratio wrappers: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/helpers/ratio/

Comment: Bootstrap 4+: Just put your `.container` inside a regular old `<div>`.

Answer (score 91):

The `container` class is intentionally not 100% width. It is different fixed widths depending on the width of the viewport.

If you want to work with the full width of the screen, use `.container-fluid`:

**Bootstrap 3:**

```
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Bootstrap 2:**

```
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span6"></div>
    <div class="span6"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span8"></div>
    <div class="span4"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span12"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: .row needs a .container or in this case .container-fluid.

Comment: If you are using the older version of bootstrap stylesheet the `container-fluid` will cause a horizontal scrollbar. To fix this add this to your stylesheet `.container-fluid{ padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto; }`

Answer (score 33):

## QUICK ANSWER

1. Use multiple **NOT NESTED** `.container`s
2. Wrap those `.container`s you want to have a full-width background in a `div`
3. Add a CSS background to the wrapping div

**Fiddles:** Simple: https://jsfiddle.net/vLhc35k4/ , Container borders: https://jsfiddle.net/vLhc35k4/1/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Section 1</h2>
</div>
<div class="specialBackground">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Section 2</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**  `.specialBackground{ background-color: gold; /*replace with own background settings*/ }`

## FURTHER INFO

### DON'T USE NESTED CONTAINERS

Many people will (**wrongly**) suggest, that you should use nested containers. 
Well, you  should **NOT**. 

They are not ment to be nested. (See to "[Containers](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container)" section in the docs)

### HOW IT WORKS

`div` is a block element, which by default spans to the full width of a document body - there is the full-width feature. It also has a height of it's content (if you don't specify otherwise).

The bootstrap containers are not required to be direct children of a body, they are just containers with some padding and possibly some screen-width-variable fixed widths.

If a basic grid `.container` has some fixed width it is also auto-centered horizontally. 

So there is no difference whether you put it as a:

1. Direct child of a body
2. Direct child of a **basic** `div` that is a direct child of a body.

By "basic" `div` I mean `div` that does not have a CSS altering his border, padding, dimensions, position or content size. Really just a HTML element with `display: block;` CSS and possibly background. 

But of course setting vertical-like CSS (height, padding-top, ...) should not break the bootstrap grid :-)

#### Bootstrap itself is using the same approach

...All over it's own [website](http://getbootstrap.com/) and in it's "JUMBOTRON" example:

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/

Comment: This answer is very thorough and adamant that nesting containers inside other containers is a 'very bad idea' (like 'crossing the streams' bad in Ghostbusters) and he points to a Bootstrap website reference that backs this up. Including a container inside a simple div is the suggestion and the fact that Boostrap use this technique on their Jumbotron example tells me that jave.web is today's winner!

Comment: that jumbotron example removed all my questions.

Comment: Sometimes it is not possible to close Container and open a new Full-with Container. The Workaround. In the following Answer is better!

Answer (score 30):

This is how you can achieve your desired setup with **Bootstrap 3**:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row"> <!-- Give this div your desired background color -->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    ... your content here ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `container-fluid` part makes sure that you can change the background over the full width. The `container` part makes sure that your content is still wrapped in a fixed width.

This approach works, but personally I don't like all the nesting. However, I haven't found a better solution so far.

Comment: Indeed it looks like "neither container is nestable" http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container, so expect a few issues here (but I'll still use your solution I think).

Comment: Its worth noting though that container-fluid class is not available in bootstrap 3.0 but is available on 3.1 and greater

Answer (score 25):

There is a workaround using vw. Is useful when you can't create a new fluid container.
This, inside a classic 'container' div will be full size.

```
.row-full{
 width: 100vw;
 position: relative;
 margin-left: -50vw;
 left: 50%;
}
```

After this there is the sidebar problem (thanks to @Typhlosaurus), solved with this js function, calling it on document load and resize:

```
function full_row_resize(){
    var body_width = $('body').width();
    $('.row-full').css('width', (body_width));
    $('.row-full').css('margin-left', ('-'+(body_width/2)+'px'));
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is extremely close to an ideal answer which does not require a change to the overall page layout, and sometimes will be sufficient, however there are subtle issues with scrollbars.  The .row-full will fill the whole window, ignoring scrollbars, unlike a container-fluid which will fill the whole window with or without the scrollbars depending on whether the scrollbar s opaque.

Comment: Wow. The js did the trick, I've been searching for hours on a solution. My issue is that the content is entered within a cms and therefore can not change the outer html. Really would like to know if there is a solution without the js.

Answer (score 23):

In bootstrap 4, you can use 'w-100' class (w as width, and 100 as 100%)

You can find documentation here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/

Comment: The best answer if you're using Bootstrap 4

Answer (score 9):

If you can't change the HTML layout:

```
.full-width {
    width: 100vw;
    margin-left: -50vw;
    left: 50%;
}
```

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">a</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">b</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 full-width">c</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">d</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/tVkNyWJxA6

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it's not possible to close the content container.
The solution we are using is a bit different but prevent a overflow because of the
firefox scrollbar size!

```
.full-width {
 margin-top: 15px;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 position: relative;
 width: calc(100vw - 10px);
 margin-left: calc(-50vw + 5px);
 left: 50%;
}
```

Here is a example: https://jsfiddle.net/RubbelDeKatz/wvt9253q

Comment: With Bootstrap 4, this is by far the best answer. Cheers!

Comment: Hardcoding values to offset one browser's scrollbars? This is a terrible hack.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
style="width:100%"
```

try using

```
class="col-xs-12"
```

it will save you 1 character :)

Comment: This answer is not what OP was asking for. This will make a column that is the full width of the outer `.container` div, but that is not the same as the full width of the page in the browser, which is what the question is asking.

Comment: I cannot see that OP requested the "full width of the page in the browser". How do you understand it?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, should have asked for your css as well. As is, basically what you need to look at is giving your container div the style `.container { width: 100%; }` in your css and then the enclosed divs will inherit this as long as you don't give them their own width. You were also missing a few closing tags, and the `</center>` closes a `<center>` without it ever being open, at least in this section of code. I wasn't sure if you wanted the image in the same div that contains your content or separate, so I created two examples. I changed the width of the img to 100px simply because jsfiddle offers a small viewing area. Let me know if it's not what you're looking for.

content and image separate: http://jsfiddle.net/QvqKS/2/

content and image in same div (img floated left): http://jsfiddle.net/QvqKS/3/

Answer (score 1):

I would use two separate 'container' div as below:

```
<div class="container">
   /* normal*/
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
   /*full width container*/
</div>
```

Bare in mind that container-fluid does not follow your breakpoints and it is a full width container.

Answer (score 0):

I'd wonder why someone would try to "override" the container width, since its purpose **is** to keep its content with some padding, **but I had a similar situation** (that's why I wanted to share my solution, even though there're answers).

In my situation, I wanted to have all content *(of all pages)* rendered inside a container, so this was the piece of code from my _Layout.cshtml:

```
<div id="body">

    @RenderSection("featured", required: false)

    <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
        <div class="container">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

In my Home Index page, I had a background header image I'd like to **fill the whole screen width**, so the solution was to make the Index.cshtml like this:

```
@section featured {
<!-- This content will be rendered outside the "container div" -->
<div class="intro-header">
    <div class="container">SOME CONTENT WITH A NICE BACKGROUND</div>
</div>
}

<!-- The content below will be rendered INSIDE the "container div" -->
<div class="content-section-b">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          MORE CONTENT
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I think this is better than trying to make workarounds, since sections are made with the purpose of allowing (or forcing) views to dynamically replace some content in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Though people have mentioned that you will need to use .container-fluid in this case but you will also have to remove the padding from bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is not exactly optimal by any measure, but I needed something that maintains its position within the container whilst it stretches the inner div fully.

https://jsfiddle.net/fah5axm5/

```
$(function() {
    $(window).on('load resize', ppaFullWidth);

    function ppaFullWidth() {
        var $elements = $('[data-ppa-full-width="true"]');
        $.each( $elements, function( key, item ) {
            var $el = $(this);
            var $container = $el.closest('.container');
            var margin = parseInt($container.css('margin-left'), 10);
            var padding = parseInt($container.css('padding-left'), 10)
            var offset = margin + padding;

            $el.css({
                position: "relative",
                left: -offset,
                "box-sizing": "border-box",
                width: $(window).width(),
                "padding-left": offset + "px",
                "padding-right": offset + "px"
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This must work (Mobile phone as well as Desktop screen):

`class: alignfull` and `class: img-fluid` will do the magic.

```
    <div class="alignfull">
                          
         <img class="img-fluid" style="background-size: cover;
                                       background-position: center ; 
                                       background-repeat: no-repeat;
                                       height: auto;
                                       min-width: 100%; 
                                       width: -moz-available; " 
         src="{{ $image->image }}" alt="An image">

   </div>
```