# element width:100% not working with container/container-fluid

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im trying to make an image header with a full width , but the image always take the container width and not 100% width (even if i put the div outside the container). i have tried almost everything and nothing worked and this answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895476/bootstrap-element-100-width) didnt help. it may be done if i change the .container width in a custom css but this will ruin the entire site design.

code:

```
<body style="background-color: #eee">

    <div class='container-fluid'>

        <div class="row" style='width: 100%'> 
            <div class='' style='height: 10px; margin: 0 0;padding: 0 0 ; width:100%'>        
                <img class=''  src="images/shape1.png" style='height: 100%; width:100%; margin-bottom: 13px'>               
            </div>
        </div>


    <div class='row text-center rowStyle' >

        <img id='leftLogo'  src="images/kslogo.png">
        <img id='rightLogo' src="images/kglogo.png">

        <div class='searchContainer'>
         <table class='table-responsive searchTable'>
                <tr>
                    <td width='15%'>
                        <img class='searchButton'  src="images/btn-search.png" >
                    </td>
                    <td width='85%'>
                        <input type='text' class="form-control searchInput">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>                                    

        </div>     

        <div class="row " style="margin-top: 40px; margin-left: auto !important;margin-right: auto !important ; width: 76%" >
            <div class="text-center col-md-4 items" >
                <img src='images/btnlog-in.png' class='buttonsLocation'>
                <img class="" src="images/Aricles03.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">        
            </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
            <div class="text-center col-md-4 items" >
                <img src='images/btnlog-in.png' class='buttonsLocation'>
                <img class="" src="images/Aricles01.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">
            </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
            <div class=" text-center col-md-4 items" style=' position: relative ;'>
                <img src='images/btnlog-in.png' class='buttonsLocation'>
                <img class="" src="images/Aricles02.png" style=''>

            </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->


        </div>
    </div>


    <div style='height: 80px; margin-top: 84px;padding: 0 0 ; width:100%; background-color:  #e3e3e3;'>

    </div>

</body>
```

EDIT: added full code + screenshot

[image]

Im using bootstrap3

any help would be appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: You need to set up a working fiddle example for us (and by "set up" I mean copy this to a fiddle, change the image's src attribute to a not local one and check if it reproduces your issue).

Comment: i will try to make a fiddle

Comment: it seems to work on fiddle but not on my code. http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/8654/ without setting images the header and footer have 100% width

Comment: i solved it , thanks Jonas .
this is a working code but the problem was in my other pages which call this page and put it in a container.

Answer (score 0):

May it be, that you forget to close the "`<div class='container-fluid'>`" tag?

Answer (score 0):

the class .container-fluid has the left and right padding set to 15px. So if you don't need that just override it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="height: 10px; padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0;">        
                <img src="images/shape1.png" style="height: 100%; width:100%; margin-bottom: 13px">               
            </div>
        </div>
```