# Bootstrap full width row with color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I purchased a theme and I am trying to edit it but I am stuck on one thing. I am trying to add a row (full width bar with text in it) that extends from one side of screen to other. It is within the container so I understand that it is limited to the containers width.

I have tried multiple options from similar questions but could not get it to work.

I have tried:
[How to create a 100% screen width div inside a container in bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049467/how-to-create-a-100-screen-width-div-inside-a-container-in-bootstrap)

[Bootstrap Element 100% Width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895476/bootstrap-element-100-width)

You can find all the code to the entire page here
http://pastebin.com/Vxxd0NDm

I am trying to add it under line 217.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure to close the div that has container class and reopen it after the section you're about to create. Then, you just do a div this way:

```
    <div class="container">
        <!-- FIRST PART OF YOUR WEBSITE, BEFORE WHAT YOU WANT TO CREATE -->
    <div> <!-- End of .container, that you're adding -->

    <!--Now the 3 row part, fullscreen 100% document width-->
        <div>
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
         </div>
  <!--Then, you reopen the container div that you have closed-->
  <div class="container">
  <!-- END OF YOUR WEBSITE, AFTER THE CODE YOU JUST ADDED -->
```

In this example, you would have 3 column that would each take 1/3 of your full page section. A div is naturally full width of the parent element. Since you close the div that contains the container before (that center your code), it will take 100% of your document width.

Look at the fiddle; dont forget to enlarge the output window in it so you don't see the mobile version: https://jsfiddle.net/oxw6tsuj/

Comment: Thats what I read before. So I need to count all the divs and find out how many I have to close and then reopen? Not sure how to just close container.

Comment: Updated my answer, you can see it in the fiddle

Comment: @ScottPilgrim you will also see how I close the container div before in the fiddle, it will provide you all you need !

Comment: @ScottPilgrim usually you should just have one container to close, and then you should reopen it if you had to close it to make it 100% width, to make sure the flow of the page is the same as it used to be before.

Comment: Not seeing how you close the container. I see you open it again?

Comment: You have to add the </div> before adding something, then, you add your code, then, you reopen the div using <div class="container"> and you're in business

Comment: Ah, I was looking on the fiddle. I did just try this and it works. I tried it earlier but wasn't sure why it wasn't working. However, this works so thank you very much!

Comment: It's my pleasure ! Have a great day