# Why bootstrap 4 row doesn't expand to full available width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

As I understand flexbox fills available space in width.
I inspected the the row many times and I really do not understand why it does not fill all available space in width. It's display flex + nothing strange here. And as you can see chrome tells that there is a lot of available space to fill.

Before this row div I created another div but only d-flex and background-red; and it worked correct and filled all available width space. While this row doesnt do this. And the question is why?

I also searched internet looking for answer but could not find any.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="col-10 pb-2 text-justify news_content">
        test
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g1xLhz6r/

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex). IMAGES OF CODE ARE NOT ACCEPTABLE.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895476/bootstrap-element-100-width I hope you'll find your answer here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the bootstrap class `.container` to `.container-fluid` and changing the class `.col-10` to `.col` gives the result you describe. Remember that `.col-10` means use 10 of the 12 available columns so puts a 1-column space on either side of that `div`.

```css
.news_content {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container-fluid"><!-- Change to container-fluid -->
  <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <div class="col pb-2 text-justify news_content">
      test
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also just eliminate the class `.container` or `.container-fluid` from the outer `div` and add the bootstrap class `no-gutters` to the div with class of `row` as shown here (you still need to use `.col` instead of `.col-10`):

```css
.news_content {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div><!-- removed class = container -->
  <div class="row no-gutters justify-content-md-center"><!-- added no-gutters -->
    <div class="col pb-2 text-justify news_content">
      test
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[no-gutters](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#no-gutters)